# development environment state for application server

Tags: jakarta-ee, ear

Is there a global flag to set to distinguish between development and production code in an `EAR` application?

Using jsf in an `WAR` there is such a flag using context parameter `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` within `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using maven? If so, you can use profiles to set a variable such as `application.project.stage` for seperate profiles named `DEV` and `PROD` and turn them off and on as needed. You can then place this variable in a properties file to be read by the application when you need it.

If you are not using maven, an alternative would be to set a system property by passing the jvmArg `-Dapplication.project.stage=DEV` then reading it using `System.getProperty("application.project.stage", "PROD");`, this means that you can leave it out of the production environment and get the default value of `PROD` when you need it.

Comment: So basically this is a homebrew solution.

Comment: Conceptually an EAR file should be unaware of it's deployment. however it can depend on variables that need to be set during setup of a server for instance. this practice is generally considered an administration task.